# Control layout via JSON add content on click

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I would like to achieve having 4 columns that show on the page that contain stacked `<divs>`'s. On the page there is forward/back buttons that add a column to the right and remove from the left (and Vice versa) but always show 4 columns.

I want to control this layout with JSON via a attribute "key" that controls the position on the 4 col layout e.g `"layout:col2"` `"Name:Matt"`. The key would also have hidden cols left and right e.g `"col-4"` to `"col+4"`, such as this:

```
var testData = {
    A: {name: "Matt", layout: "col1"},
    B: {name: "Aaron", layout: "col2"},
    C: {name: "Dan", layout: "col3"},
    D: {name: "James", layout: "col4"},
    E: {name: "Roy", layout: "col-1"},
    F: {name: "Tim", layout: "col+1"},
}
```

Problems are:

1: Not displaying 4 cols to start with - add remove functionality is working but not in the conveyer style.

2: JSON controlling positioning

To demonstrate what I have so far, which contains the rough layout with add remove buttons,

http://plnkr.co/edit/ai6cg0K47Cjh6U9MaUo9?p=preview 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mtrug2cgmc4QHqOGnZk0?p=preview

Comment: Instead of uploading them on dropbox, create a plnkr, its much easier and ready to run inside the browser

Comment: Please see plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ai6cg0K47Cjh6U9MaUo9?p=preview

PS if you click "add" 4 times, this is the state the layout should look like on load

Comment: So i have made some adjustments on this plinkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mtrug2cgmc4QHqOGnZk0?p=preview

I have added JSON & used a filter to change the order of the output and used css to control the positioning. 

This hasn't solved the issue as I wanted to assign a Col value to each object to position it. Any help would be well received.

 thanks Matt

Comment: Your buttons in plnkr are not connected to anything in your controller.

Comment: Hi A.Alger, Many thanks for your feedback. Yes I need the buttons to work like this plnkr.co/edit/ai6cg0K47Cjh6U9MaUo9?p=preview. However Im not sure if I can put some vertical formatting in the JSON to create 4 visible columns. I can only see a orderBy filter in Angular, but want to sort 4 (but add more later) different data sets. If i can manage that then ill look at having the buttons add hidden elements.